# is there a JRE reduced version for Tomcat only?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a web application that uses embedded Tomcat, which I'll distribute as a desktop app. Since I don't want users to deal with the installation of JRE, I decided to bundle JRE in my installation package, however, I was wondering if there's a reduced version of JRE in order of having a smaller installation file size. For example, I removed all the CORBA related files from JRE and everything seems to be working fine, so I guess some other files could be removed without affecting Tomcat's functionality, but I really don't know which other files should I remove.

If anyone has done this before, I'd appreciate your comments.

Comment: I lol at anyone that thinks there's an embedded Java anything.

Comment: The new modules feature in java9 is touted as doing this _sort_ of thing. I haven't looked yet at the details, but noticed the license is changed to specifically allow redistribution of 'portions of [Java] produced by jlink ... for sole use with [an app]'. Incidentally I don't see why a Tomcat/web app couldn't reasonably use CORBA; AWT JavaFX Nashorn OTOH ....

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll take a look at java9. And yes, Tomcat could use all these CORBA, AWT, JafaFX  etc, however, my app doesn't use any of those libraries.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there aren't any official cut-down Oracle JRE releases.  Certainly not free ones, though I imagine Oracle would create one for a customer who was willing to pay (enough).

If you created and distributed a cut-down JRE based on the Oracle JRE, it would be a violation of the Java Binary license ... which expressly forbids such things.  You would need to get permission from Oracle to do this.  The same applies to other suppliers, so the chances of you finding a free cut-down JRE based on OpenJDK are "vanishingly small".

I'm don't know for sure the legal constraints on building a cut-down JRE starting from the OpenJDK open-source codebase.  I suspect that it is legal from the copyright perspective, but that you need to understand of patent and trademark issues.  (For example, a cut-down JRE would not pass Java Standard Edition TCK testing, so you would not be permitted to use trademarked terms like Java and JRE to describe it.)

You should to talk to a lawyer if you intended to build and distribute cut-down JREs to anyone else.

I understand that Azul distributes cut-down JREs as a commercial (non-free) offering.  Google found [this](https://github.com/zulu-openjdk/meta-zulu-java/pull/3) for me:

> The short answer for why we do not remove contents of Zulu JDK is for compliance with Java Standard Edition TCK testing. Changing the contents of tested build after the fact is often believed to be an invalidation of TCK coverage, and we cannot ship without that copyright/patent/trademark umbrella. Secondly, Azul offers cut down JREs and Compact Profile binary builds as a commercial (non-free) offering. We still need some way to monetize Zulu (else the business is not self sustaining) so charging fees and offering only private access to the set of lean & mean production runtimes is core to our business model.

Comment: I haven't distributed it, I just deleted 2 folders that are not needed for running Tomcat and I had no idea that it was "ilegal". I didn't modify any code either. Anyway, I'll do more research on that subject, thanks for your comment.

Comment: It is not illegal ... unless your distribute it.  However, I fail to see to point of creating a stripped down JRE if you don't intend to distribute it.  It is only disk space, and disk space is cheap.